# stopping the ip connection between a client and the server for 30seconds and rewarm up of the link after that period

Tags: network-programming, iptables

Here is my configuration:

On the server I have a dhcp server that gives IP addresses to clients (connected on eth1) in order for the clients to be connected to the internet (on eth0).

For a special operational use, I would like to stop the IP connection between a client and the server for 30 seconds and rewarm up the link after that period. Currently I have tried to use iptable black list to put the client IP inside the black ip list with this command:

command 1: sudo iptables -I INPUT -s '.$ip.' -j DROP

then I use another iptable command to resume the ip link with this command:

command 2: sudo iptables -D INPUT -s '.$ip.' -j DROP

the both commands are encapsulated in a PHP program stored in an Ubuntu server and launched from a Windows workstation. Both command works perfectly but, unfortunately, I never get the internet connection back. From a Windows command screen I can monitor the behaviour of the line with ping commands. Here are the result of command 1:[stop the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhqQI.png)

Here are the result of command 2:[start the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV81Z.png)

Here is my Question:

Can someone thell me how to rewarm up the local IP socket in order to relaunch the tcp connection after command 2?

Another way of doing this may could have be to stop using iptable command and dynamically modify the lease time of the client IP address given by dhcp service.

Stopping the connection: by anticipating the end of lease period of the IP address. Rewarming up the connection: by attempting a http command to invoke the establishment of a tcp connection with a new lease time.

Can someone tell me how to overcome this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you sure this question has something to do with software programming?

Comment: Our goal is to cut the communication between a dhcp client and the dhcp server dynamically (php bash ...) I do not know if the socket can do this work

Comment: What TCP connection are you talking about: from which TCP client host, to which TCP server host, on which TCP destination port?

Comment: We want to cut off communication between the dhcp server and one of its clients at port 68

Comment: This will not block anything, since DHCP does not use TCP on port 68.